# How to use 2 identicals action calls with different params on the same page with Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need your help, I've been looking for a solution for a while and haven't been able to find something. I'm doing a React website with Redux and I have my components, my containers, actions, reducers etc. And sometimes I need to use two identical containers on the same page but with different params.

```
<TeamContainer teamID='123'/>
<TeamContainer teamID='456'/>
```

And each container dispatches the same action "Fetch Team Data" with the teamID. So Redux first asks for team data for team 123 and then for team 456 but when it comes to reduce data, the second call "erases" the first one. I know it's normal and usefull to update data but in this case I don't know how to avoid it properly.

How am I supposed to do ? Any tip ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my tip:
try store data in arrays, there is not overwrited.

https://hackernoon.com/redux-patterns-add-edit-remove-objects-in-an-array-6ee70cab2456